# glDrawPixels puts each RGB component in a different pixel

Tags: c++, opengl, gldrawpixels

As the title says, Red Green And Blue values are put into different slots, making the screen have stripes of red green and blue.
the code is pretty much: (`w` and `h` are width and height...)

```
unsigned int pixels[w * h * 3];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < w * h * 3; i+=3) {
    pixels[i + 0] = 0xff // Red
    pixels[i + 1] = 0xff // Green
    pixels[i + 2] = 0xff // Blue
}
while(windowIsOpen()) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawPixels(w, h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    glSwapBuffers();
}
```

But, this produces and image like this when it should be all white:
[image: Not what I want]

Any help would be amazing! I know `glDrawPixels` is deprecated but I need an easy way to draw pixels on the screen, performance isn't an issue for this project.

Comment: and if you allocate the pixels array with unsigned char?

Comment: If ints are 4 bytes wide in your system, pixels will have this pattern in memory: 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 FF ...
But then in the glDrawPixels you are specifying GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, meaning OpenGL is expecting RR GG BB RR GG BB ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that you are using a buffer of ints (sizeof(int) = 4 ) while you are telling your opengl that you are sending UNSIGNED_BYTE (sizeof(char) = 1).

Change your buffer from int to char and see if everything goes fine.

Comment: Also be sure to set the appropriate value for `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT)`

Comment: I know it's a bigger data type, yet I've seen examples that look nearly identical to this using unsigned integers as well that work.